# The new child element contains the parent. при создании блока div через const

Tags: javascript

Возникает ошибка при создании блока div. Первый блок div создался без проблем в body с id root, после я присвоил класс firstContainer, чтобы при помощи класса добавить div внутрь 1 блока div

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
document.querySelector('#root').append(div)
document.body.lastElementChild.classList.add('firstContainer')
```

Но, когда я хочу добавить внутрь таким образом:

```js
document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(div)
```

Возникает нелогичная мне, но логичная браузеру ошибка, что child содержит parent.
Ведь я просто упростил код `const div ...//`,
но вот так работает

```js
document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(document.createElement('div'))
```

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
document.querySelector('#root').append(div)
document.body.lastElementChild.classList.add('firstContainer');
document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(div)
```

```html
<body id="root"></body>
```

Comment: Приведи цельный пример кода, который не работает.

Comment: последняя строчка работает логично, потому что добавляется **новый** элемент. Какой элемент ты пытаешься добавить в `document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(div)` - неизвестно. И из текущего кода - это не ясно

Comment: @Grundy Это и есть весь код, он состоит из body и 2 div: 

`const div = document.createElement('div'); document.querySelector('#root').append(div) document.body.lastElementChild.classList.add('firstContainer') document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(div)` 

Это весь код, в котором возникает ошибка Я пометил тег js faq, потому что это основы DOM, но я просто не могу понять, почему из-за упрощения кода, у меня возникает ошибка

Comment: @Grundy но вот так `document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(document.createElement('div'))`
работает, хотя я переменной div упростил себе написание куска кода `document.createElement('div')`

Comment: это не весь код, очевидно. Во-первых, не хватает разметки, во-вторых, неизвестно что и когда вызывается. В любом случае даже в текущем виде ты не просто "переменной упростил" ты добавил две лишние строки. Если ты просто вынесешь в переменную - все продолжит работать

Comment: @Grundy ладно, мне стыдно за свою глупость, но это действительно весь код, а разметка состоит из `<body id="root">` 
Все остальное вызывается в порядке написания. спасибо за отзывчивость, если до вечера не будет ответа, удалю вопрос\\ Может чтобы понять в чем моя проблема, напишу чего хочу добиться: Внутри `body` 1 `div`, а внутри этого другой `div`

Comment: Я добавил сниппет в твой вопрос - у тебя такой код? Или отличается?

Comment: @Grundy так точно! 
Если что я продолжить кодить, просто без использования сокращения и получаются длинные строчки, и для меня странно, что не работает с переменной

Comment: все работает с переменной, просто ты хочешь добавить див сам в себя, а не добавить в него новый элемент

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за отзывчивость, как тут лайк поставить? Удалю тогда вопрос попробую перепроверять

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в коде не в том, что `document.createElement('div')`, а в том, что эта переменная используется дважды.

1. добавляется в элемент с `id="root"`
2. добавляется в элемент с `class="firstContainer"`

Однако, во втором случае элементом с `class="firstContainer"` является тот самый див, который хранится в переменной.

Из-за этого возникает парадокс: попытка добавить элемент, в самого себя.

И, как следствие, ошибка.

Для добавления нового элемент, нужно его просто создать перед добавлением.

Например:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
document.querySelector('#root').append(div)
document.body.lastElementChild.classList.add('firstContainer');
var container = document.querySelector('.firstContainer');

console.log(container === div);

const div2 = document.createElement('div');
document.querySelector('.firstContainer').append(div2);
```

```css
.firstContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.firstContainer>div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body id="root"></body>
```